# Invalid prop `accounts` of type `object` supplied to `AccountList`, expected an array

Tags: redux, action

I imported a json file in my file and i created an action like this:

```
import jsonData from './data/account_list_response.json';
const inAccountsList = () => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'ACCOUNT_LIST',
      state: {
        accounts: jsonData
      }
    });
};
```

Then, i make the accounts as prop in my accountList container like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { accounts: state.get('accounts').map(account => account.toJS()) };
}
```

and finally

```
const AccountList = ({ accounts }) => (
  <div className="account-list">
    <h4 className="table-header">Accounts</h4>
    <Table hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Account Number</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Balance</th>
          <th>Available Balance</th>
          <th>Currency</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {accounts.map((account, i) =>
          <AccountEntry
            key={account.id} idx={i + 1}
            {...account}
          />
      )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  </div>
);
```

An error occured Invalid prop `accounts` of type `object` supplied to `AccountList`, expected an array. Why is that??

Comment: Do you have a [`propTypes`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) somewhere?

Comment: yes AccountList.propTypes = {
  accounts: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    accountNumber: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    balance: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    balanceAvailable: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    currency: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired
};

Comment: my json file is like this {
    "id": "00260001010000000001",
    "accountNumber": "0026.0001.01.0000000001",
    "description": "My account #1",
    "balance": 42.0,
    "balanceAvailable": 42.0,
    "currency": "EUR"
  }

Comment: Ok, well that's why it's expecting an array.

Comment: And how im able to fix this??

Comment: Where's your reducer code?